# Deploying Custom YOLOv8 on Android

Tags: android, yolov8, ncnn

I trained my own yolov8 model. I converted it to onnx format. I added my .bin and .param files to android. But it didn't work.

A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xc33813d4 in tid 4260 (ImageReader-640), pid 4229 (cent.yolov8ncnn)
I have this error now.

https://medium.com/@gary.tsai.advantest/top-tutorials-for-deploying-custom-yolov8-on-android-%EF%B8%8F-dd6746afc1e6
I followed this tutorial.

I would love any ideas, Thank you.

android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
I tried  this.